# Global array in header file... is it mandatory to specify the size?

Tags: c++, arrays, global-variables

Somewhere I read that it is possible to declare an (global) array in a header file without specifing the size. Something like this:

```
 // Header
 extern int MyArray[];

 // CPP file
 int MyArray[] = { 1, 4, 16, 512, 8192 };
```

But when I try to compile, I get the compiler error `invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'double []'`.

Am I missing something? Does the compiler force you to specify the array size in case of forward declarations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with your declaration or definition. The problem is that you're trying to apply `sizeof` to `MyArray` despite the fact that it has an incomplete type (because it's size has been left out).

There's a bit of a hacky way round it, using a companion variable to store the size:

```
// Header
extern int MyArray[];
extern size_t MyArraySize;

// CPP file
int MyArray[] = { 1, 4, 16, 512, 8192 }; 
size_t MyArraySize = sizeof(MyArray);
```

Now you can use `MyArraySize` in other translation units to determine the size of `MyArray`.

However, instead of using this method, I'd recommend just giving the size of the array (or avoiding global variables all together).

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't going to specify the size of the array then you need to track its current size separately and the compiler won't know this size at compile time and hence you cannot use `sizeof()`:

.h:

```
extern int MyArray[];
extern size_t MyArrayLen;
```

.cpp:

```
int MyArray[] = { 1, 4, 16, 512, 8192 };
size_t MyArrayLen = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone... It was my fault indeed, I didn't notice that the error arose from another part of the code, where there was a call to `sizeof(myArray)`.